# Android background notifications vibration

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-vibration

I think like I searched whole internet at this point and time my question is: **Is it even possible to make android phone vibrate on firebase notification?** I tried everything but I was only able to make it vibrate in foreground.

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    vibrator.vibrate(1000)
}
```

}

This is piece of code that I ended up with. Super simple but working

Comment: are you add vibrate permisson on manifirst file ?

Comment: @milanpithadia is correct, you **must** add vibration permission in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

please confirm you have add vibrate permission on manifest file or not

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: ibrator v = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

try this

Comment: I use kotlin so It dosen't work it's the same like getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator